# add a row to an already sorted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe that I've sorted:

```
    df = df.sort_values(
        by=['col1', 'col2'],
        kind='quicksort', # 'quicksort', 'mergesort', 'heapsort'
    )
```

Then I receive a new row to add to the dataframe.  I could add it to the end and re-run the sort, but that feels inefficient.  I believe the computer would re-check that EVERYTHING is in the correct order.  But all that needs to be done is to insert the new row in the appropriate place.

How would I implement the more efficient method?

### For example

This is just an example.  I am still looking for a general answer.

Suppose my sorted dataframe looks like

```
  politician                 name zip-code   tx-date  tx-amount
2  C00384818       ABBOTT, JOSEPH    02895  01122017        250
4  C00384516       ABBOTT, JOSEPH    02895  01122018        333
5  C00384516      SABOURIN, JAMES    02895  01312018        384
1  C00177436    DEEHAN, WILLIAM N    30004  01312017        384
3  C00177436  JEROME, CHRISTOPHER    30750  10312017        384
...
```

and contains some 40,000 rows of data.  I want to insert the row

```
C00384516      SABOURIN, JAMES    02895  01312017        230
```

into the dataframe.  The result should look like

```
      politician                 name zip-code   tx-date  tx-amount
    2  C00384818       ABBOTT, JOSEPH    02895  01122017        250
    4  C00384516       ABBOTT, JOSEPH    02895  01122018        333
40001  C00384516      SABOURIN, JAMES    02895  01312017        230
    5  C00384516      SABOURIN, JAMES    02895  01312018        384
    1  C00177436    DEEHAN, WILLIAM N    30004  01312017        384
    3  C00177436  JEROME, CHRISTOPHER    30750  10312017        384
```

Comment: Show us some sample data

Comment: I think it depends on the data you're trying to sort. In same cases, it is "easy" to insert a row in the appropriate place, since you have an "easy" way to find that correct place. If you don't have a simple way to insert the row, then you would need an incremental sorting algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting#Incremental_sorting ). It is not a trivial problem.

Comment: Why do you care about it constantly being in a sorted state?  What does it get you?